# Is there a way to compare cell values and then colour cells based on the value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two columns of data (column G and column N) - both are in the same worksheet.

I am trying to get my code to do the following:

```
Compare the value of N4 with G4.
If N4 is < G4, color red, 
If N4 = G4, color yellow,
If N4 > G4, color green. 
Repeat this for all active cells in those columns.
```

It's been a while since I used Macros and I can't get my head round how to pull this together. The code below is where I'm at, but this only colors a cell in column N if it is equal in value to "7". This is the bit I'm struggling with - how do I get the color to change by comparing it to column G? If anyone can help pull this together, it would be much appreciated!

I've tried conditional formatting, but i want the scope to add in more color options and potentially edit if the value of N is within a % of G.

```
Sub ColourCode()

lRow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("N4:N" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
If cell.Value = 7 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
Next
End Sub
```

Formula works fine for coloring based on a fixed value - just won't compare to column G

Comment: Why don't you use conditional formatting for that? There is no VBA needed for this. You can build more than one rule with conditional formatting.

Comment: Hi Peh, I've tried conditional formatting but I've used macros in the past and found they are much easier to edit once created and I'm looking for flexibility in changing the macro once written, rather than having to create new rules each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `cell.Value` is a cell in column N `Range("N4:N" & lRow)` then you need to offset `-7` columns to go from `cell` to column G.

```
If cell.Value = cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-7).Value Then
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! This is working fine. I've extended it out to match the color I want... Here's the final code:

Comment: Sub ColourCode()

lRow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("N4:N" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
If cell.Value > cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-7).Value Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
If cell.Value = cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-7).Value Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 9
If cell.Value < cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-7).Value Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

Next
End Sub